# Display stacked histogram by looping over clusters within df

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I have a dataset that includes all the batting averages of baseball players. I assign each player in this dataset randomly to a cluster. Now I want to visually display each cluster in a stacked histogram. I use the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def chart(k=2):
    x = np.arange(0, 0.4, 0.001)
    for j in range(k):
        cluster = df.loc[df['cluster'] == j].reset_index()
        plt.hist(cluster['Average'], bins=50, density=1, stacked=True)
    plt.xlim(0, 0.4)
    plt.xlabel('Batting Average')
    plt.ylabel('Density')
    plt.show()
```

This gives me the following output:
   [image]

However, I would like to see the following:

[image]

I created this chart by dividing the dataset "hard-coded". Ideally, I want to do it dynamically by creating a loop. How can I also add a legenda with the clusters names and specify the color for each cluster? Again all in a loop. *K* can also be 10 for example.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Not providing data and a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 to people before asking a question makes it difficult to answer your problem. This is something you should keep in mind for the next time. Nevertheless, here is one way that should work for you. The idea is to create an axis object `ax` and pass it to plot both the histograms on the same figure. Then you can modify the labels, limits etc. outside the function after plotting everything.

P.S: As poited out by Paul H in comments below, the DataFrame `df` and the column names should be passed as arguments to the chart function as well to make it more robust

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def chart(ax1, k=2):
    x = np.arange(0, 0.4, 0.001)
    for j in range(k):
        cluster = df.loc[df['cluster'] == j].reset_index()
        ax1.hist(cluster['Average'], bins=50, density=1, stacked=True)
    return ax1

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax = chart(ax, k=2)    
plt.xlim(0, 0.4)
plt.xlabel('Batting Average')
plt.ylabel('Density')
plt.show()
```

Comment: just a thought: the dataframe and column names should be arguments to the `chart` function

Comment: @PaulH: You are right. I will leave that on the OP to take care of that. I will add your suggestion to the answer in words though. Thanks!